# Get Types Collection from EntityFramework ObjectContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

How can I extract list of `Types` from `ObjectContext`?

For example, I have object context containing an entity named "Bank" and entity named "Company".
I want to get the EntityObject type of them.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you at run-time want to query the generated `ObjectContext` class to get a list of `EntityObject` classes. It then becomes an exercise in reflection:

```
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = objectContext.GetType().GetProperties();
IEnumerable<Type> entityObjectTypes =
  from propertyInfo in propertyInfos
  let propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType
  where propertyType.IsGenericType
    && propertyType.Namespace == "System.Data.Objects"
    && propertyType.Name == "ObjectQuery`1"
    && propertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityObject))
  select propertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

This code will find all public properties on the object context that has type `System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<T>` where `T` is a subclass of `EntityObject`.

Comment: In EF4.0, only if remove this line:&& propertyType.Name == "ObjectQuery`1", the results will be ok, otherwise return nothing. Could you explain?

Comment: You can have types in your context, that do not have a DbSet property on the context, no?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Dynamic Data this becomes easier, I just did this in one of our apps

```
MetaModel.GetModel(objectContext.GetType()).Tables.Select(t => t.EntityType);
```